# React Test : Finding Component within Component

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-testutils

I can find a component at the first 'finder' in the code below

```
var myComponent = ReactTestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithClass(myDiv, 'myComponent')
```

If I then use the returned Component object and use that to find an even deeper object like so :

```
var myInput = ReactTestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithClass(myComponent, 'myInput')
```

I get this error :

> Invariant Violation: findAllInRenderedTree(...): instance must be a
>   composite component
>       at invariant (node_modules/fbjs/lib/invariant.js:44:15)

I cannot figure out what the type is that is returned from **findRenderedDOMComponentWithClass** because (a) Javascript and (b) ReactTestUtils has [barely any documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/test-utils.html#findrendereddomcomponentwithclass).

My entire test looks like this :

```
import ReactTestUtils from 'react-dom/lib/ReactTestUtils';

describe('simple test', function() {

  jsdom({ skipWindowCheck: true });

  it('Getting Simulate to Work', function() {
    class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <div className="myComponent">
            <input type="textfield" className="myInput" ></input>
            <span className="child1" />
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
    var myDiv = ReactTestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
      <SomeComponent/>
    );
    var myComponent = ReactTestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithClass(myDiv, 'myComponent')
    var myInput = ReactTestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithClass(myComponent, 'myInput')
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting that error because `myInput` isn't a composite component. It's a native browser input. Composite components are components made from `React.Component` (not divs, or spans, or inputs or buttons, etc).

You could instead add a `ref` to your input:

```
<input type="textfield" className="myInput" ref="myInput">
```

and find it using `React.findDOMNode`:

`React.findDOMNode(this.refs.myInput)`

(where `this` here refers to an instance of the component containing the input, meaning in your case you'd need to call this inside the definition of SomeComponent somewhere).

and then you should only use `findRenderedDOMComponentWithClass` to find components which are instances of `React.Component` (i.e. react components that you define as classes and register as a component with react with `class SomeComponent extends React.Component`).